# WPF Style Triggers in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers, binding

i hope you can help me. I got following Code in the Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="img_src_lock" UriSource="/EEBase;component/Images/Lock_24x32.png" />
  <BitmapImage x:Key="img_src_unlock" UriSource="/EEBase;component/Images/Unlock_24x32.png" />
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource img_src_lock}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource img_src_unlock}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  <!-- TypeComboTemplateCollapsed -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeComboTemplateCollapsed">
    <TextBlock 
      Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="5,0,0,5"
      />
  </DataTemplate>
  <!-- TypeComboTemplateExpanded -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeComboTemplateExpanded">
    <TextBlock 
      Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="5,0,0,5"
      />
  </DataTemplate>
  <!-- EditCircleTemplate -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="EditCircleTemplate">
    <!-- some content here, no ToggleButton -->
  </DataTemplate>
  <!-- EditRectangleTemplate -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="EditRectangleTemplate">
    <!-- some other content here, including the ToggleButtons -->
    <ToggleButton
      IsChecked="{Binding Path=BaseLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
      Margin="5"
      />
    <ToggleButton
      IsChecked="{Binding Path=HeightLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
      Margin="5"
      />
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

To me that looks all correct.

Now, the problem is:
When i do the following, an exceptions occurs:
**Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.**
1. load the control, selected type is CIRC
2. change the dropdown to select RECT (template triggers and togglebuttons are shown correctly)
3. change the dropdown back to CIRC
--> now the Exception occurs.
4. if i ignore the exception, the template "EditCircleTemplate" does not get loaded, and the normal ToString of the model object gets displayed.

Additional info:
originally there are 4 different types in the WPF, two of them with ToggleButtons (that's why i use templates). I cut them out, they dont differ really. But what i found out using all 4 templates is that the error does not occur when switching to a new Template, but when **unloading a template with the toggle buttons**. Which is kinda strange.
Also if i remove the DataTriggers for the ToggleButtons everything works like a charm.
The Exception comes from the XAML-Interpreter, so the Stacktrace is not useful at all.

Can anyone give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

Edit:
oops, i guess i forgot the content code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox 
        Margin="5"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PossibleTypes, Mode=OneTime}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="content" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TypeComboTemplateExpanded}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TypeComboTemplateCollapsed}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <ContentControl
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <ContentControl
                    Name="inputContent"
                    Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                    ContentTemplate="{x:Null}" 
                    />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger 
                        Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedType.Type, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        Value="CIRC">
                        <Setter 
                            TargetName="inputContent" 
                            Property="ContentTemplate" 
                            Value="{StaticResource EditCircleTemplate}"
                            />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger 
                        Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedType.Type, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        Value="RECT">
                        <Setter 
                            TargetName="inputContent" 
                            Property="ContentTemplate" 
                            Value="{StaticResource EditRectangleTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

**Edit2/Solution:**
I just found a workaround - it just does not satisfy me:
Instead of putting the style in the UserControl.Resources, which for me would be the more clean and intuitive solution, i have to set the style with the triggers on **each ToggleButton separately**.
So removing the  and adding following code to each ToggleButton did the trick:

```
<ToggleButton.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource img_src_lock}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource img_src_unlock}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
```

The big question still persists: **WHY?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you create an `Image` in a style there is only one instance, so as soon as multiple controls use the style there is going to be a fight over this one instance which can only be owned by one control.

The easiest solution to this is placing the Style in a resource and setting [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) to false, that way a copy of the style is used whereever referenced.

Comment: Hm, sounds reasonable. Just why did the Exception also occur when i switched from the Template WITH buttons to one WITHOUT ?

Comment: @gelse: Maybe that causes the trigger to fire, which leads to the conflict again. This may happen before the template is actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create BitmapImages and set them as Source to your Content Images in Triggers? Why arent you using the URI source to Images directly?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"> 
      <Style.Triggers> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"> 
          <Setter Property="Content"> 
            <Setter.Value> 
              <Image Source="/EEBase;component/Images/Lock_24x32.png" /> 
            </Setter.Value> 
          </Setter> 
        </DataTrigger> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False"> 
          <Setter Property="Content"> 
            <Setter.Value> 
              <Image Source="/EEBase;component/Images/Unlock_24x32.png" /> 
            </Setter.Value> 
          </Setter> 
        </DataTrigger> 
      </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That does not change anything. Same error.
Honestly, i dont know any more why i did use the BitmapImages. I think it was because initially i wanted the ImageSource to be bindable. so i had to choose between either a ImageSource object on the model or the String to the URI and load it with the BitmapImages.
That also means that the images are loaded only once into memory. I am not sure if that is the case if you use the URI.

Comment: ah - and right now i am pretty sure that the problem is because the framework tries to set the TRIGGER twice. i have no idea if that is possible and why it raises an error, but it seems the best explanation to me.